# randrename -- insert random nums in filenames

Tags: python, random

I have an old mp3 player with a broken screen. Consequently, it's a real pain to turn shuffle mode on and off; however, there are a few albums that I wanted to mix together and have shuffled for when I'm working out.

That led me to whip up something in Python -- the first successful result was only about a dozen lines and could strip the track numbers from the beginning of files' names and replace them with random numbers.

I wanted to learn argparse for another [more complicated project](http://github.com/ryran/pyrite), so I took the opportunity to spruce up my randrename script today.

I started playing with Python in mid-December, but have been doing so in a vacuum with no peer-review, so.... I would happily receive any and all kinds of feedback you can offer. I'm quite confident in my general logic skills, so I'm most interested in any tips for making things more Pythonic. Thanks for reading this far!

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
#
# Last file mod: 2012/02/21
# Latest version at <http://github.com/ryran>
# Copyright 2012 Ryan Sawhill <ryan@b19.org>
#
#    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
#    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
#    (at your option) any later version.
#
#    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU
#    General Public License <gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html> for more details.
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

import random
import os
import argparse
from textwrap import dedent
from sys import stderr

progname='randrename'

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    prog=progname,
    description=dedent("""
        Insert random numbers into filenames or replace filenames with random numbers,
        optionally stripping characters from the beginning or end of said filenames.
        """),
    formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
    epilog=dedent("""
        ins-pos may be specified as (examples):
           0  rand num will be inserted at beginning of filename
           2  rand num will be inserted after the 2nd character of filename
          -1  rand num will be inserted after the last char of filename
          -3  rand num will be inserted after the 3rd from last char of filename

        NOTES:
          All operations (e.g. ins-pos, crop-right, and kill-name) are performed on the
          name of FILE sans its file extension. Use ignore-ext to change this behavior.

          If kill-name is specified, ins-pos, left-strip, & crop-right will all be
          ignored (if they're specified).

          Lastly, if any cropping is requested, it will be performed before the random
          number (+ any specified separator chars) are inserted into the filename.

        EXAMPLES:
                [EXAMPLE CMD]                   [POSSIBLE OUTPUT]
          {prog} toaster.mp3            ==> '71toaster.mp3'
          {prog} -s '. ' toaster.mp3    ==> '20. toaster.mp3'
          {prog} -i1 toaster.mp3        ==> 't66oaster.mp3'
          {prog} -i-1 -S_ toaster.mp3   ==> 'toaster_24.mp3'
          {prog} -d3 -s. toaster.mp3    ==> '395.toaster.mp3'
          {prog} -d4 -k 01.bak          ==> '8353.bak'
          {prog} -d4 -kx 01.bak         ==> '7279'
          {prog} -l2 -r1 01-AB.mp3 02-ZX.mp3.zip  ==> '50-A.mp3' '38-ZX.mp.zip'
        """.format(prog=progname)))

parser.add_argument('filenames', metavar='FILE', nargs='+',
                    help="file(s) to operate on")
parser.add_argument('-i', '--ins-pos', metavar='N', type=int, default=0,
                    help="position in filename to insert rand num (default: 0)")
parser.add_argument('-d', '--num-digits', metavar='N', type=int, default=2,
                    help="num of digits to use for rand num range (default: 2)")
parser.add_argument('-S', '--lsep', metavar='C', default='',
                    help="separator char(s) to prefix the random number with")
parser.add_argument('-s', '--rsep', metavar='C', default='',
                    help="separator char(s) to append to the random number")
parser.add_argument('-l', '--lstrip', metavar='N', type=int, default=None,
                    help="number of chars to strip from beginning of filename")
parser.add_argument('-r', '--rstrip', metavar='N', type=int, default=None,
                    help="number of chars to strip from end of filename")
parser.add_argument('-w', '--wstrip', action='store_true', default=False,
                    help="strip whitespace from beginning/end of filename")
parser.add_argument('-k', '--kill-name', action='store_true', default=False,
                    help="remove filename completely (excluding extension)")
parser.add_argument('-x', '--ignore-ext', action='store_true', default=False,
                    help="disable special treatment of file extensions (e.g. if used with --kill-name, extension is removed as well)")
args = parser.parse_args()


def get_path_components(fin, ignore_extension=False):
    """Break filename into component parts, i.e. path, filename, extension."""
    # Split the path from the actual filename
    head, tail = os.path.split(fin)
    # Split filename and extension, unless ignoring extension
    if ignore_extension:
        filename = tail
        ext = ''
    else:
        filename, ext = os.path.splitext(tail)
    return head, filename, ext


def generate_randint(num_digits, end):
    """Generate num_digits-long zero-filled random integer between 0 & end."""
    return str(random.randint(0, end)).zfill(num_digits)


def update_filename(args, filename, ext, random_num):
    """Munge filename (& potentially extension), dependent on options in args namespace."""
    if args.wstrip:
        # Strip leading/trailing whitespace if requested
        filename = filename.strip()
        ext = ext.strip()
    # Strip num of chars from left & right
    filename = filename[args.lstrip:args.rstrip]
    # If negative index, need to modify it
    if args.ins_pos < 0:
        index = len(filename) + args.ins_pos + 1
    else:
        index = args.ins_pos
    # Insert random_num into filename at proper index
    filename = filename[:index] + random_num + filename[index:]
    return filename, ext


# If negative num-digits supplied, flip the sign
if args.num_digits < 0:  args.num_digits *= -1

# Calculate high end of random number generation range
rand_max = 10 ** args.num_digits - 1

# If right-strip was supplied, convert it to negative
if args.rstrip > 0:  args.rstrip *= -1


# Process each file
for fin in args.filenames:

    # Split fin into component parts
    head, filename, ext = get_path_components(fin, args.ignore_ext)

    # Prefix/append separator char(s) to random number
    num = args.lsep + generate_randint(args.num_digits, rand_max) + args.rsep

    # Replace filename with random num or insert rand num into filename
    if args.kill_name:
        filename = num
    else:
        filename, ext = update_filename(args, filename, ext, num)

    # Join file path, name, & extension
    fout = os.path.join(head, filename + ext)

    # Rename!
    try:
        os.rename(fin, fout)
    except OSError as error:
        stderr.write("Error renaming FILE {!r}: {}\n".format(fin, error[1]))
    else:
        print("Renamed: {!r}  ==>  {!r}".format(fin, fout))
```

(Or at github, https://github.com/ryran/b19scripts/blob/master/randrename)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Figure out high range for random number generation, based on num-digits arg
rand_max = 0
for n in xrange(args.num_digits):
    if rand_max == 0:   rand_max = '9'
    else:               rand_max += '9'
rand_max = int(rand_max)
```

This whole loop can be written as `rand_max = int('9' * args.num_digits)` or `rand_max = 10**args.num_digits - 1`

```
# Need to tweak this a little to make it optional
if args.rstrip == 0:
    args.rstrip = None
elif args.rstrip > 0:
    args.rstrip = args.rstrip.__neg__()
```

You should almost never called **functions**. Instead use `-args.rstrip`

```
# Process each file
for fin in args.filenames:
```

I recommend using `filename` rather then `fin`

```
    # Skip to the next file if no write permission on file
    if not os.path.isfile(fin):
        print("FILE {!r} not found".format(fin))
        continue
    elif not os.access(fin, os.W_OK):
        print("No write permission for FILE {!r}".format(fin))
        continue
```

`continue` is rarely helpful. You should almost always use `else`. I also recommend catching exceptions rather then trying to check failure conditions.

```
    # Split the path from the actual filename
    head, tail = os.path.split(fin)

    # Split filename and extension, unless ignore-ext opt provided
    if args.ignore_ext:
        filename = tail
        ext = ''
    else:
        filename, ext = os.path.splitext(tail)

    # Generate random number, zero-filled and prefix/append separator char(s)
    num = args.lsep + str(random.randint(0,rand_max)).zfill(args.num_digits) + args.rsep

    # Replace filename with random num or insert rand num into filename
    if args.kill_name:
        filename = num
    else:
        if args.wstrip:
            # Strip leading/trailing whitespace if requested
            filename = filename.strip()
            ext = ext.strip()
        # Strip num of chars from left & right
        filename = filename[args.lstrip:]
        filename = filename[:args.rstrip:]
```

You should be able to combine these two lines

```
        # Insert random number at proper position
        if args.ins_pos < 0:
            # If negative index, need to modify it
            args.ins_pos = len(filename) + args.ins_pos + 1
```

It makes more sense to do this outside of your loop.

```
        filename = filename[:args.ins_pos] + num + filename[args.ins_pos:]

    # Join file path, name, & extension
    fout = os.path.join(head, filename + ext)

    # Rename!
    print("Renaming: {!r}  ==>  {!r}".format(fin, fout))
    os.rename(fin, fout)
```

Overall, it would be helped by using more functions. I'd aim for a body something like:

```
head, filename, ext = path_components(args, fin)
random_number = generate_random_number(args)
filename = update_filename(args, random_number, filename)
fout = os.path.join(head, filename + ext)
```

Comment: **1)** I love `rand_max = int('9' * args.num_digits)` and `rand_max = 10**args.num_digits - 1` -- I knew there was a way to make that block better. I feel kinda silly now. :) Can't decide which one to use either. **2)** I'd like to hear more on what you said about continue. I'm not convinced. My solution is succinct and simple and avoids having to indent the rest of the file. Why is this so bad? **3)** I don't see what you're talking about when you say "You should be able to combine these two lines". **4)** I also don't see how to do what you're saying (at the end) outside the loop.

Comment: Because, as the code stands now, I need to mess with the value of filename, which is inside the loop.

Finally: I took a KISS philosophy with this project -- it just didn't seem worth it to split the logic up into functions. But I'll play with that. THANKS for your feedback!

Comment: A reason occurred to me for why you might have not liked my error-checking + continue statement at the beginning of the for loop. While that kind of setup would be more efficient if there were tons of bad filenames, it comes at the cost of being less efficient on good filenames. So I get it. I changed it to a try/except block around the rename at the end. Thanks again for making me think. :)

Comment: @ryan, `continue` is a bit of a personal preference thing. If you look at the equivalent `else` and `continue` versions, I think the else version is easier to follow. If you put `continue` it makes if act like an if/else, so I figure you should use an if/else. I guess I don't see saving a level of indent as worthwhile.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something you should be able to use `filename = filename[args.lstrip:args.rstrip]`.

Comment: Regarding 4, you are right, I missed that. But it seems to me that your code is wrong. You modify args at that point  given the length of the current filename. But what happens with the next filename? It'll use the value you calculate here.

Comment: I find that almost any amount of logic is worth splitting into functions. Again, that's a personal style issue. I think its much easier to grasp the overall logic of your new version without getting bogged down in the details.

Comment: Regarding checking vs try/except. You are correct that this is going to generally be more efficient. Your original loop has to make three system calls which are really expensive. The new loop has to make a single system call. The best that could happen for the first loop is to bail out after the first call, leaving it at best only slightly more efficient then the try/except loop. Additionally, the status of a file could change while your program is running. If that happens, your checks will pass and then you'll get an exception trying to actually rename the file.

Comment: Admittedly thats kinda far fetched. But using try/except: that case will be handled correctly. Also, what if you missed a failing case? You can be pretty sure that no matter what goes wrong with renaming it, the exception code caught it. Can you say the same for the if-checking code? Stylistically, I also think it produces easier to follow code. Overall, catching exceptions rather then detecting failing conditions generally works better. Lastly, your `except: raise` bit doesn't do anything (except waste cpu cycles).

Comment: **(A)** You _are_ missing something with condensing args.lstrip & args.rstrip into one line. **(B)** WOW! You're absolutely right about #4. Thanks for catching that. I'm shocked I made that mistake. **(C)** Re logic/flow/functions: After pondering it a bit, I kinda landed on that same side of the fence as you just described -- that even if it makes the script longer, it allows one to take a quick glance and grasp the main flow without focusing on all the details. **(D)** Good point on file-status changing during operation. In the end I definitely came to appreciate the whole try/except logic.

Comment: Ahhh. I get what you mean about the `except: raise`. I've been doing it wrong. :)

Comment: PS: You weren't missing anything about how I could condense two lines down to `filename = filename[args.lstrip:args.rstrip]`. I was dumb. Thanks again.